# Custom Transaction type

Tags: transactions, block

I'm trying to create a layer 2 blockchain. In this blockchain, I do some computing to add to a transaction. Basically, I want to add a custom type to store in the block alongside Extrinsics.

Are there any examples of this? Or, where should I take a look at the source code?

Comment: You are asking you add something additional to your block header? Or what does "along side Extrinsics" mean?

Comment: "Extrinsic" just means "external data". It does not necessarily need to be signed or (immediately) actionable, so you probably just want to define a new kind of extrinsic? Did you look at the Inherents/`InherentData` API? See pallet_timestamp for a simple example.

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi Yes, I want to add additional data to the block header. Thanks, @ Gav, I'll take a look.